# What means this line?

Tags: php, html, forms, get, isset

```
$n = isset($_GET["n"]) ? $_GET['n'] : '';
```

I find this "method" to avoid errors before insert stuff in the input type.. and it works.. but I would like a detailed explanation of this line. Thank you!

Comment: It's called a [Terniary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Think of it as a one line if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the `ternary operator` shorthand of `if...else`

```
(condition) ? true : false
```

There is a condition which has been checked on left, if its true the statement after the `?` will be execute else the statement after the `:` will execute.

Answer (score 0):

It's called **Ternary operator**

The ternary operator is a shorthand for the `if {} else {}` structure. Instead of writing this:

```
if ($condition) {
    $result = 'foo' 
} else {
    $result = 'bar'
}
```

You can write this:

```
$result = $condition ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

If this `$condition` evaluates to `true`, the lefthand operand will be assigned to `$result`. If the condition evaluates to `false`, the righthand will be used.

### In your case

If the value of `$_GET["n"]` isset then it'll take `$_GET["n"]` value.

if the value is not set then it'll take `('')` value.

```
$n = isset($_GET["n"]) ? $_GET['n'] : '';
```